# Moment js gives unexpected dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to work with dates, but this gives me unexpected dates when using it.

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().startOf('day').toDate());
```

```js
console.log(moment().startOf('day').toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This prints: `2020-10-13T21:00:00.000Z`.

Why does it print `9PM`? Should it print `12AM`?

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you midnight local time, but you're printing it out in zulu time. Try using toString instead, it will print the time out in local time.

Try `moment().startOf('day').toString();`

Comment: At first I thought it was a daylight savings issue, but that would explain it being `23:00:00`, not `21`. I feel like it's gotta be a timezone issue, think you've got it right